# validate field and save with tinyMce

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi everyone I have a _form in rails, it is work and good.

I have to include a TinyMce in one fields I do it and now I have this...

```
= form_for @idea do |f|
  - if @idea.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@idea.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this idea from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @idea.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, :required => true
  .field
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description,  :class => "tinymce", :cols=>"25", :rows=>"5", :required => true
    = tinymce
```

the problem now if that I use required => true, and with tinymce option don't save the form, because the form thinks that this field is empty, but don't show me any error, and don't save too.

any idea,